# migrating interrupt GPIO program available in DOS to Linux

Tags: c, linux

I am writing an application which requires to count incoming pulses to `PC104`.

I am using [`Puppy Linux`](http://puppylinux.org). I have an example program in `DOS` for interrupt [`GPIO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_input/output) but now am facing a problem in migrating that code in Linux. Can anyone help me to full fill my requirement by this or any other method?

Here is DOS code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<dos.h>

typedef void interrupt (far *FNISR) (...);
FNISR _pfnOldIsr;
unsigned int _nIrqNo;
unsigned int _nIntNo;
unsigned int _nOldImr;
unsigned int _nOldImr2;
static unsigned long _lCnt = 0;

void interrupt NewIsr(...)
{
    cprintf("IRQ %d trigger. (%lu)\r", _nIrqNo, _lCnt++);
    outp(0x9f, 0xff);
    if(_nIrqNo > 7)
       outp(0xa0, 0x20); //**
    outp(0x20, 0x20);
    // send EOI command
}
// Disable warning message "Parameter xxx is never used
#pragma warn –par
// Write south bridge register
void write_sb(unsigned char idx, unsigned long val)
{
    _asm mov dx, 0cf8h
    __emit__(0x66); __emit__(0xb8);
    __emit__(0x00); __emit__(0x38); 
    __emit__(0x00); __emit__(0x80);
    _asm mov al, idx
    __emit__(0x66); __emit__(0xef);
    _asm mov dx, 0cfch
    __emit__(0x66); __emit__(0x8b); __emit__(0x46); __emit__(0x08);
    __emit__(0x66); __emit__(0xef);
}

int main(int nArgCnt, char *pszArg[])
{
    if(nArgCnt != 2)
    {
        printf("\nUsage: %s <IRQ_NUM> \n", pszArg[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    // Install ISR for IRQ
    _disable();
    _nIrqNo = atoi(pszArg[1]);
    _nIntNo = (_nIrqNo <= 7) ? (_nIrqNo + 8) : (_nIrqNo + 0x70 - 0x08);
    _pfnOldIsr = getvect(_nIntNo);
     setvect(_nIntNo, NewIsr);
     unsigned char byMask = 0x00;
     switch(_nIrqNo)
     {
        case 9:byMask = 0x01;break;
        case 3:byMask = 0x02;break;
        case 10:byMask = 0x03;break;
        case 4:byMask = 0x04; break;
        case 5:byMask = 0x05; break;
        case 7:byMask = 0x06; break;
        case 6:byMask = 0x07; break;
        case 1:byMask = 0x08; break;
        case 11: byMask = 0x09; break;
        case 12: byMask = 0x0b; break;
        case 14: byMask = 0x0d; break;
        case 15: byMask = 0x0f; break;
     }
     if(byMask == 0x00)
     {
        printf("\nError IRQ number.\n");
        return 1;
     }
     printf("Using IRQ %d\n", _nIrqNo);
     // set 8259 interrupt controller
     if(_nIrqNo <= 8)
     {
       _nOldImr = inp(0x21);
       outp(0x21, _nOldImr & (~(1 << _nIrqNo)));
     }
     else
     {
       _nOldImr = inp(0x21);
       outp(0x21, _nOldImr & (~(1 << 2)));
       _nOldImr2 = inp(0xa1);
       outp(0xa1, _nOldImr2 & (~(1 << (_nIrqNo - 8))));
     }
     printf("Test Port0: active low, trigger once\r\n");
     unsigned long val = 0xffff0000L | ((0xA0 | byMask) << 8);
     val = ((val << 8) | 0x0000ffffL) & 0x00ffffffL;
     write_sb(0xdc, val);
     _enable();
     getch();
     _disable();
     write_sb(0xdc, 0x0000ff00L);
     if(_nIrqNo <= 8)
     {
        outp(0x21, _nOldImr);
     }
     else
     {
        outp(0x21, _nOldImr);
        outp(0xa1, _nOldImr2);
     }
     setvect(_nIntNo, _pfnOldIsr);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: PC104 isn't that important in this context, quite probably the PIO chip on the IO card is an 8255 or compatible.  Can you give some details about the IO extension card you are using?

Comment: the processor is VDX6354D from icop.

Comment: what exactly you want please tell me

Comment: That's the CPU board.  Are you using a separate IO board or is the GPIO function integrated in the cpu board?  I can't access their doc without registering...  What I meant: as in many cases x86 GPIO uses the 8255 chip of a derivative thereof, chances are your board is also using that chip, and there's quite some software for that chip already floating around.  See eg [here](http://www.pci8255.net/linux.htm)

Comment: no 8255 is there, I will copy and paste information given in processor data sheet below,                                  General Programmable I/O
– Supports 40 programmable I / O pins – Each GPIO pin can be individually configured to be an input/output pin 
GPIO_P0~GPIO_P3 can be program by internal 8051
–GPIO_P0 and GPIO_P1 with interrupt support (input/output)

Comment: actually i don't know how to write interrupt service routine for this particular board.. please please do help if you can... my application is to count incoming pulses from incremental and optical encoder

Comment: So you seem to be using the integrated GPIO of the Vortex86 processor.  Unfortunately, as far as I can see that there is no Linux support for that CPU's GPIO available.  You will have to write your own kernel GPIO driver, you should be able to use the existing material for the 8255 as a starting point.  It won't be easy though

Comment: Can we do it with the method other than Interrupt GPIO? can you suggest me some sample codes in Linux which handles external interrupts? my job is to interface optical encoder and to count incoming pulses to VDX-6354D,whatever is the way to do it doesn't matter.

Comment: Please excuse me if I am asking any fullish question because I am very new to Linux programming and very confused about the things.

Comment: No, the question is not foolish, but I have no readymade solution, I'm afraid that you will have to write or find a kernel driver.  If you need to write one I'd suggest to start off one of the existing GPIO style drivers in the kernel, have a look at the kernel sourcetree for a suitable candidate.  But it won't be easy.

Comment: then what should I do?

Comment: That depends on factors like skills available, project resources available and number of devices to produce.  Just some ideas  Option 1: build, or have built, a kernel driver for you specific board - won't be easy but if you're developing for a production of many pieces, it may be worthwhile.  Option 2: switch to a PC104 DIO board with decent Linux support - good if you will only be producing a very low number of devices.  Option 3: use an extra microcontroller, program the fast IO work in there and have it communicate with the Linux side eg over serial or USB.

Comment: do you have any example codes for 8959 interrupt controller?

Comment: It's in the Linux kernel source, but you should not mess around at that level.  To get started, read the [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) book.